# How do I get the Current time in milliSeconds in a Shell script in buildroot environment?

Tags: shell-scripting, linux-kernel, buildroot

```
MYENV=$(date +"%s%N")
printf "Time:: %s\n" "$MYENV"
```

or

```
MYENV1=$(date +"%T%N")
printf "Time:: %s\n" "$MYENV1"
```

I tried above methods, they do work in regular linux but not working in buildroot.

`1606718041%N` is the output being printed.
What does this mean? Is this a specific format? How to decode this?
(If I'm not wrong this is the time since epoch, correct ?)

Comment: If %T is working and %N isn't my guess would be that the version of `date` in your build environment is a version that doesn't support that sequence.

Comment: try running `\date`, or run it with an absolute path to make sure you run the same binary from your manual run and not an alias or a replacement.

Comment: The [documentation of GNU date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html#Time-conversion-specifiers) states that `%N` is a GNU extension, so it's not surprising if it doesn't exist in other implementations of `date`